# Regex not equal operator?

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to return a function if the NAMESPACE variable is blank or if the VERSION variable doesn't match the correct pattern.

```
# return usage if namespace is blank or version doesn't match the version format.
if [[ "$NAMESPACE" == "" || "$VERSION" =~ ^([0-9]\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[0-9])$ ]];
    then
        usage
fi
```

Currently I'm using `=~` which returns true if the pattern is x.xx.x or x.x.x. But I'm having trouble finding what the operator would be for not equal (something similar to `!=~`)

Comment: `! "$VERSION" =~ ^([0-9]\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[0-9])$`

Answer (score 0):

You can negate after the `||` for a `(A OR NOT B)`:

```
if [[ "$NAMESPACE" == "" || ! "$VERSION" =~ ^([0-9]\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[0-9])$ ]];
    then
        usage
fi
```

Note that you need to have spaces around the `!`.

Alternatively you can reverse the `(A OR NOT B)` to `NOT (NOT A AND B)`:

```
if ! [[ "$NAMESPACE" != "" && "$VERSION" =~ ^([0-9]\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[0-9])$ ]];
    then
        usage
fi
```